# Efficient way to implement a client multiple file upload service

Tags: java, javascript, model-view-controller, spring, jsp

1. What is an efficient way to implement a multiple file client upload service?
   Are there any popular libraries for that?
   Basically I'm looking at a Web view, served a client, that would allow them to upload files: i.e browse their file system and choose say up to 6 files.
2. Is implementing the above service better than a single file upload-service. i.e allowing only one upload at a time?
   If so what is an efficient way to implement that or again what popular libraries are there to use.

I'm building a Java Dynamic Web to be deployed on Tomcat.

Thanks

Comment: It should be very easy to do in spring 3. Look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart this worked great for us.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do multiple file uploads on the web, I would strongly recommend [SWFUpload.](http://swfupload.org/)  It's totally customizable, and it can use whatever back end technology you'd like.  Take a look at some of the demos on the site for some use cases involving multiple files at once.  I've only used it in one project so far, but it beats some of the other third party upload controls I've used hands down.

Comment: Thanks, well mostly allowing users to upload files via a Java Web Application. I'm also considering the tradeoffs of allowing users to, browse their local file system and upload multiple files, say (6 files allowed at a time) or perhaps doing so one file at a time

Answer (score 2):

If your clients can use modern builds of browsers, you can use multiple file upload field support that mozilla/webkit offers. Otherwise, YUIUpload from latest YUI3. Much cleaner/faster/easier than SWFUpload.

Comment: I've never used the YUI uploader, but from the example (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/uploader/uploader-simple-button.html) it sure doesn't look any faster or easier to implement :)

Comment: Their documentation is whack, but code is written by other folks who are very talented. Trust me, digging through their docs will pay off. SWFUploader is ancient.